# Create RestFul API without framework dependency?

Tags: php

I'm going to create my own RestFul API, my idea is create a simple API that allow me to execute `GET - POST - DELETE - PUT` operation on database. The `GET` method will return a `json` so I can elaborate it in any frontend interface. 
Now my question is: is a good way don't use a framework? How the project structure should be set? Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that is Not mandatory to have a framework to build your **Rest API**. You can go to this link and Have a look to this Tutorial [Rest API without framework in php](http://anantgarg.com/2009/03/13/write-your-own-php-mvc-framework-part-1/).

This tutorial beautifully explains how to accomplish your goal without any Framework.

but I will suggest to go for one of them because of the following **reasons**:

1. Easy and less effort/Time is required.
2. Safe and Secured..
3. Updated Framework support with time.
4. Customized Features.
5. Not to worry about Structuring.

Some of the **great Frameworks** for Php is as follows

1. Phalcon
2. Lumen
3. Slim
4. Silex

Comment: Very good tutorial, I have search a lot on the web and I didn't d found it. Thanks. Anyway with a framework I should learn all of the framework structure, while writing a restful api I am me that I manage my code.

Comment: there is another tutorial that can allow me to achieve this result: http://api.football-data.org/index ? How you can see I want just put an url with some parameter and the code automatically call the properly function.

Comment: Hmmm if this facilitates you to do more.....Then obviously this is good..But  I only shown you the way  to do so...Their could be many... :)

Comment: On the net all tutorial are based on Slim or other framework, there isn't much material without framework :(

Comment: Yes actually at Enterprise level application no one prefer to have their own Framework that is why the tutorials are less available...One more thing if you make your own Framework suppose u have to leave from that project and somebody else have to overtake its responsibility it will be very hard to understand your framework...If you have used Slim or other fw it will be easy  for anyone to pick from any point of time.

Comment: Interesting point of view, so this framework are used also in professional application sold by large companies? Could you suggest a good tutorial for Slim as the example of the link above? Token access, GET, POST and so on? Thanks :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103381/discussion-between-sevengames-xoom-and-mani).

Comment: its a mvc example, not a Rest API example